# why does it show compiler error if i initialize the array whose size is not specified?

Tags: arrays, c, initialization

Why does this show compiler error if i don`t specify the size of the array before and try to initialize it?

```c
int main()
{

    int ar[] = {};
    
    int n = 5 ; 
    for(int i = 0; i  < n ; i++)
        ar[i] = i+1;
    
}
```

Comment: You don't have a size associated with your array. How is it supposed to know how much memory to allocate?

Comment: regarding; `int ar[] = {};` This does not compile!  Your compiler should have told you that.

Comment: But it does compile, even without warning, allocates a zero-sized array, and on the first operation tries to set the first element, which results in UB. On my machine with GCC it modifies the value of `n` to be `i+1`, which then ends the loop after one iteration. But it could just as well crash with a segfault.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Then your compiler settings are missing, add them to catch issues and have a conforming code.

Answer (score 2):

From `C11`, chapter 6.7.6.2,

> *In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static`, the `[` and `]` may delimit an expression or `*`. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero. The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type. The optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static` shall appear only in a declaration of a function parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost array type derivation*

So, this syntax

```
int ar[] = {};
```

is a constraint violation. If you enable basic compiler warning, you should see something like

```
In function ‘main’:
error: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Werror=pedantic]
     int ar[] = {};
                ^
error: zero or negative size array ‘ar’
     int ar[] = {};
```

Comment: This happens when setting `-pedantic` for GCC, but does not for either `-Wall` or `-Wextra`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer *why* there is a compiler error, maybe it's useful to think about the structure of the memory used by the program.

When the program is executing the function referenced in the question it adds a frame to the stack.

"Adding a frame" just means the information for the current function is added onto the end of the stack and when  the program runs the code it needs to also create space for the array.

To me the given syntax could only mean a dynamically sized array, meaning items could be added or removed arbitrarily resizing the structure.

The problem with this is that arrays are stored on the stack and since there's usually things added after the function variables in the frame of a function there's no space to add more items to the array!

Therefore it seems like C would create many issues by allowing this use and specifying a size for your array allows the program to use that amount of space in the stack which causes no memory issues with the stack during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring and initializing a [zero-length array (GNU C extension)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) in that line:

```
int ar[] = {};
```

The uses of zero-length arrays are rare (e.g. tail padding structs, for alignment purposes), and your code does not look like it's meant to be using it, so you are probably doing so by accident.